# How do I deal with event start time and end time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having an Issue where I have to input Event **start_date**, **start_time**, **end_date**, and **end_time** in my development.

How do I deal with my database tables in such case? Am looking at outputting Date and **Event Start Time** as is in the picture below:

[image]

Here is what I have in my migration structure:

```
class CreateEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :events do |t|
      t.datetime :start_date
      t.datetime :end_date

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

How do I deal with event start time and end time?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking--you already have two datetimes, which store date and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very straight forward. Create the table as per your migration. Then, store the date and time in **start_date** and **end_date** columns. Then when you want to display the values you have to use the **strftime** to format the values accordingly.

To get the date in dd/MM/YYYY format,

```
start_date.strftime('%d/%M/%YYYY')
```

To get the time,

```
start_date.strftime("at %I:%M%p")
```

Comment: So I can choose event start time from the frontend during creation of event with datetime-picker.